# Image Slider JS some problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Tabbed Slider some problems.
Hi guys i have some problem. my tabbed gallery doesnt work or working but not match working. 
button2 and button3 clicked but showpanel not working every time. i need some help you can see every problems.
and i wanna add autoslider but its have so many problem. what can i do ? i need help. Thanks.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, showpanel, smtbutton;
  showpanel = document.getElementsByClassName("showpanel");
  for (i = 0; i < showpanel.length; i++) {
    showpanel[i].style.display = "none";
    
  }
  smtbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("smtbutton");
  for (i = 0; i < smtbutton.length; i++) {
    smtbutton[i].className = smtbutton[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  
  
  
}//ikinci benim yer

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
   if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius: 15px ;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.showpanel {
  position: relative;  
  width:900px;
  height:337px;
 display: none;
}


.mySlides {
  display: none;
  width:900px;
  height:337px;
   
}
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  
}
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height:10%;
  
}
.demo {
  opacity: 1;
}
.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.smtbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 16px ;
  background-color: #a1cf49 ;
  border: 0px;
  color: #314d47;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  left:21%;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 13px;
  
}
.smtbutton #smtspan {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.smtbutton #smtspan:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0; 
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.smtbutton:hover #smtspan {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.smtbutton:hover #smtspan:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="smtop">
<button class="smtbutton" onclick="openTab(event, 'smta')" id="defaultOpen"><span id="smtspan">Button1 </span></button>
<button class="smtbutton" onclick="openTab(event, 'smtb')" > <span id="smtspan">button2</span></button>
<button class="smtbutton" onclick="openTab(event, 'smtc')"> <span id="smtspan">button3</span></button>
</div>
<div id="smta" class="showpanel">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div  class="mySlides fade ">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
  
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
     <div class="mySlides fade ">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" >
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(7)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(8)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(9)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(10)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="smtb" class="showpanel">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
  
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
     <div class="mySlides fade ">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(11)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(12)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(13)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(14)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(15)" >
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(16)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(17)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(18)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(19)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(20)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="smtc" class="showpanel" >
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
  
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
     <div class="mySlides fade ">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(21)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(22)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(23)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(24)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(25)" >
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(26)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(27)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(28)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(29)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(30)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this may be help full i am first element display block of every tabs by adding `document.getElementById(tabName).firstElementChild.style.display ="block";`.

Logic only when tab active inner first element also will be vissible and same ID not use again and again.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, showpanel, smtbutton;
  showpanel = document.getElementsByClassName("showpanel");
  for (i = 0; i < showpanel.length; i++) {
    showpanel[i].style.display = "none";
    
  }
  smtbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("smtbutton");
  for (i = 0; i < smtbutton.length; i++) {
    smtbutton[i].className = smtbutton[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
document.getElementById(tabName).firstElementChild.style.display ="block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  
  
  
}//ikinci benim yer

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
   if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius: 15px ;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.showpanel {
  position: relative;  
  width:900px;
  height:337px;
 display: none;
}


.mySlides {
  display: none;
  width:900px;
  height:337px;
   
}
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  
}
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height:10%;
  
}
.demo {
  opacity: 1;
}
.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.smtbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 16px ;
  background-color: #a1cf49 ;
  border: 0px;
  color: #314d47;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  left:21%;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 13px;
  
}
.smtbutton #smtspan {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.smtbutton #smtspan:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0; 
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.smtbutton:hover #smtspan {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.smtbutton:hover #smtspan:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="smtop">
<button class="smtbutton" onclick="openTab(event, 'smta')" id="defaultOpen"><span id="smtspan">Button1 </span></button>
<button class="smtbutton" onclick="openTab(event, 'smtb')" > <span id="smtspan">button2</span></button>
<button class="smtbutton" onclick="openTab(event, 'smtc')"> <span id="smtspan">button3</span></button>
</div>
<div id="smta" class="showpanel">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div  class="mySlides fade ">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
  
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
     <div class="mySlides fade ">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" >
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(7)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(8)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(9)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(10)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="smtb" class="showpanel">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
  
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
     <div class="mySlides fade ">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(11)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(12)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(13)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(14)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(15)" >
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(16)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(17)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(18)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(19)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(20)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="smtc" class="showpanel" >
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade ">
  
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
    
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
     <div class="mySlides fade ">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div> <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n17.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(21)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n11.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(22)" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r15.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(23)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(24)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(25)" >
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n20.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(26)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r18.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(27)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/r14.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(28)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(29)">
    </div> <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.banco.com.tr/uploads/n10.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(30)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its Working ! Thank you!

Comment: But have some problem if i select button1 someone currentslide and select button2 its show two showpanel. how can fix that ? my brain not working this banner i tried too much and my brain done :/

Comment: if you use bootstrap then use bootstrap tab and use bootstrap carousel in tab content or use jquery plugins.